# How to let Excel pick up several numbers that give a sum wanted?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I'm not sure how I can phrase the question better but please see the image attached below. Basically, in the example, I have a number as the goal, 10 (on the left). Then, I have a number list on the right with a bunch of numbers that I can choose from. I'm looking for a way to select a certain number of numbers from the number list to make the sum of those numbers equal to the goal number. In the example below, the correct answer is a choice of "5", "3", and "2".

Any excel functions, tools in the menu bar, or VBA codes are welcome.

[image]

Comment: I found this answer [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/looking-for-a-specific-sum-within-a-range-of-numbers.49138/post-225740) using Excel's Solver Add-in. He mentions a VBA way but does not provide it but I will see if I can as this is interesting. In the meantime at least if you do want to try this method you first need to activate the add-in. In order to get the add-in working, you need to go File>Options>Add-ins>Select "Solver Add-in", click "Go..." at the bottom, check "Solver Add-in" and click ok. You should then see it show up somewhere in the Data tab.

Comment: Once you have the solver you can have 3 changing cells as binary and use sumproduct to calculate the total, then set solver to make the total equal to the goal stated.

Comment: My first thought of this is also solver and I came up with an idea of using dummy variable as Mike suggested. However, it didn't work for me and I was very confused. But thank you for mentioning that I need to uncheck the "...interger..." box. That was tricky haha...

Comment: @JackeyOL if you posted this comment about my answer - it would have helped if you had commented directly then I would have seen it. As it is I show two worked examples of using the solver to correctly solve your question so unless you provide more info I can only assume you made an error of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to make a VBA solution for this. I have tested with multiple different goals/targets & different range of numbers to sum and worked every time. Can't guarantee there isn't a problem it won't work around though.

Here it is:

**Note - you should be able to now have multiple of the same number. This will only return the first solution it finds. It doesn't find EVERY solution.**

```
Sub SumSolver()

Dim rng, Goal As Double, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, Answer As Double, k As Long
Dim lRow As Long, Answerlist As String, LastAdded As Long, AnswerListPos As String
Dim c As Range, RngToSplit As String, AnswerArray, AnswerItem

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change Sheet1 to your sheet name
lRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change to needed column
ws.Range("C2:C" & lRow).ClearContents 'Clear output range if needed

For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B" & lRow) 'This loop populates the list range into a string
    If c.Value <> "" Or Not IsNumeric(c.Value) Then 'Checking for empty or non-numeric values
        If RngToSplit = "" Then
            RngToSplit = c.Value
        Else
            RngToSplit = RngToSplit & "," & c.Value
        End If
    End If
Next
rng = Split(RngToSplit, ",") 'Split the new list string into an array

If Not IsNumeric(ws.Range("A2").Value) Then 'Checks target value is actually a number
    MsgBox "The target value is not a valid number. Please correct this before trying again.", vbExclamation, "Sum Solver"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Goal = ws.Range("A2").Value 'Value of the goal/target
End If

For i = 0 To UBound(rng) ' 0 = start of array, Ubound = End of array
    If rng(i) = Goal Then
        ws.Range("C2") = rng(i)
        Answerlist = rng(i)
        GoTo SubExit
    ElseIf rng(i) < Goal Then
        Answer = rng(i)
        Answerlist = rng(i)
        AnswerListPos = i
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(rng)
            If Answer + rng(j) = Goal Then
                Answerlist = Answerlist & "," & rng(j)
                AnswerListPos = AnswerListPos & "," & j
                GoTo SubExit
            ElseIf Answer + rng(j) < Goal Then
                Answer = Answer + rng(j)
                LastAdded = j
                If Answerlist = "" Then
                    Answerlist = rng(j)
                    AnswerListPos = j
                Else
                    Answerlist = Answerlist & "," & rng(j)
                    AnswerListPos = AnswerListPos & "," & j
                End If
            End If
            If j = UBound(rng) Then
                If LastAdded = UBound(rng) Then
                    Answerlist = Left(Answerlist, InStrRev(Answerlist, ",") - 1)
                    AnswerListPos = Left(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") - 1)
                    Answer = Answer - rng(j)
                    LastAdded = Val(Mid(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") + 1))
                End If
                If LastAdded > 0 Then Answer = Answer - rng(LastAdded)
                If InStr(Answerlist, ",") = 0 Then Exit For
                j = Val(Mid(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") + 1))
                Answerlist = Left(Answerlist, InStrRev(Answerlist, ",") - 1)
                AnswerListPos = Left(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") - 1)
            End If
        Next j
    End If
    Answerlist = ""
Next i

SubExit:

If Answerlist <> "" Then
    i = 2
    AnswerArray = Split(Answerlist, ",") 'Split the result into an array
    For Each AnswerItem In AnswerArray
        ws.Range("C" & i) = AnswerItem 'Output the results into the sheet
        i = i + 1
    Next
Else
    MsgBox "No possible combination found for a target value of " & Goal & ".", vbExclamation, "Sum Solver"
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Just updated to account for if there are any blank rows in the list range as well as handle if a value is non-numeric. Actually made it half a second faster (13s) for a 12 item list of 1000 iterations.

You will see the rows I've made comments on are the ones you need to change. Pretty much just what columns it is working on and the starting cell It works looking at the last row but if you don't need it then just replace for example `"B2:B" & lRow` with `B2:B5` etc.

**I've also incorporated it into a function. Used as:**

`=SumSolver(Target value, Range of sum values)`

It returns the results in the same cell separated by a comma. This can be changed to another method easily if needed though.

```
Function SumSolver(Goal As Double, ListRange As Range)

Dim i As Long, j As Long, Answer As Double, k As Long, rng As Variant
Dim Answerlist As String, LastAdded As Long, AnswerListPos As String

rng = Application.Transpose(ListRange)

For i = 1 To UBound(rng)
    If rng(i) = Goal Then
        Answerlist = rng(i)
        GoTo SubExit
    ElseIf rng(i) < Goal Then
        Answer = rng(i)
        Answerlist = rng(i)
        AnswerListPos = i
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(rng)
            If Answer + rng(j) = Goal Then
                Answerlist = Answerlist & "," & rng(j)
                AnswerListPos = AnswerListPos & "," & j
                GoTo SubExit
            ElseIf Answer + rng(j) < Goal Then
                Answer = Answer + rng(j)
                LastAdded = j
                If Answerlist = "" Then
                    Answerlist = rng(j)
                    AnswerListPos = j
                Else
                    Answerlist = Answerlist & "," & rng(j)
                    AnswerListPos = AnswerListPos & "," & j
                End If
            End If
            If j = UBound(rng) Then
                If LastAdded = UBound(rng) Then
                    Answerlist = Left(Answerlist, InStrRev(Answerlist, ",") - 1)
                    AnswerListPos = Left(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") - 1)
                    Answer = Answer - rng(j)
                    LastAdded = Val(Mid(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") + 1))
                End If
                If LastAdded > 0 Then Answer = Answer - rng(LastAdded)
                If InStr(Answerlist, ",") = 0 Then Exit For
                j = Val(Mid(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") + 1))
                Answerlist = Left(Answerlist, InStrRev(Answerlist, ",") - 1)
                AnswerListPos = Left(AnswerListPos, InStrRev(AnswerListPos, ",") - 1)
            End If
        Next j
    End If
    Answerlist = ""
Next i

SubExit:

If Answerlist <> "" Then
    SumSolver = Answerlist
Else
    SumSolver = "N/A"
End If

End Function
```

Example:

[image: Sum Solver Script in action]

I decided to do an update of my speed test. This time comparing the updated code against my original, and was surprised to see the difference. I did runs of 1000 iterations where the solver could not find a combination. I did this with screen updating on. For a list of 8 there is a max of 255 combinations, for a list of 12, there is a max of 4095 combinations (doubles with each item added). For a list of 12, that comes to 4,095,000 calculations. Updated code did that in an average of 13.6 seconds. Obviously this is on my machine, which will have different results to yours (but the ratios should still be about the same).
[image: Sum Solver speed test]

Comment: Great answer Simon. Is it possible to make it able to handle cases where there are duplicates in the number list, such as [11, 9, 5, 3, 3, 2] and there should be 2 correct answers [5, 3(1st), 2] and [5, 3(2nd), 2]

Comment: Ive almost cracked the duplicates but do you need it to provide all possible solutions? Cause thats another issue really and makes it a lot more difficult. Definitely could be done in VBA but would have to have a think as to how to make it not repeat itself to find another option. What is the need to find multiple solutions?

Comment: @JackeyOL I've updated the answer, have a go with multiple of the same number and see if it works good for you.

Comment: This is wonderful. A quick question (sorry if this sounds silly), I copied to code into a module but wasn't able to call the function using `=SumSolver()`. What am I doing wrong? @Simon

Comment: It should be in a regular module not a sheet module. Also if your calling from VBA it's just `SumSolver(options)`, but you can use it in regular cells like a normal formula using `=SumSolver(options)`.

Comment: you are definitely correct and your solution works like a charm. It turns out that I accidentally clicked ctrl F11 instead of alt F11 when I tried to bring up the VBA editor which caused the code not to work at the beginning.@Simon

Answer (score 0):

So, just like this:

[image]

```
=sumproduct(C5:C10,D5:D10)
```

is the formula in cell B8 and is the objective in the Solver.

The two constraints control the model and DO check the options to make sure "Ignore Integer" is NOT selected.

Binary is used as this is a selected or not selected situation.

I used equal to in the constraint, but in some situations you may need to use <= or >= as there may not be an exact solution.

The Solver also deals with multiple values the same, unlike the other answer, however, as there are multiple solutions then which ones are picked are random:
[image]

Comment: "unlike the other answer". The solver solution was my initial answer which you can see by my comment above but I also posted the VBA option because I believe it to be better. After testing both methods, the VBA solution is way easier and miles faster than the solver which is slow and tedious, which is why I changed my answer to being a VBA solution. I only comment after just seeing your edit.

Comment: @Simon have you corrected the issue with the code not working with 2 or more of the same number? Solver handles that and it takes about a second to solve on my machine, which is not **too** much time, especially since your code takes 25 or more seconds...

Comment: If you look at my answer I show the time it takes to do 1000 iterations (of no success, which means looping through all possible outcomes). A single sum is instant. The gif shows a single sum. Solver was taking a couple seconds for equivalent calculation. I am currently working on a solution to allow multiple of the same number.